# Why is this power calculating function crashing?

Tags: c

I tried following function (as suggested on these forums) to calculate power. However, it is causing program to hang up.

```
static long ipow(int b, int e) {
    long r = 1;
    while (e--) r *= b;
    return r;
}

double cfilefn(int a, int b, int c) {
    return (ipow(a, b) / (double)c); 
}

cfilefn(2,3,4);
```

The function looks all right. Where is the error and how can it be solved?

Comment: works fine for me - returns 2. Once I added a main that is.  So this isnt the code you are running (given that it doesnt compile) so please post the actual code

Comment: It worked on my PC, with the parameters 2, 3, 4 anyway. Are those the same parameters that cause the hang? Passing some inconvenient value for `e`, such as -1, would make more sense as a cause of such misbehaviour

Comment: Do you use `cfilefn()` in a loop? "Hang" sounds like your program is stuck somewhere, maybe a comparsion that fails because of the inaccuracy of `double`s? I'm just guessing here

Comment: I was trying to call this C function from Python. So the error must be somewhere else. I will soon be deleting this question.

Comment: If you are writing in C, why is Python involved? Check how the arguments are being provided to the C function from Python. That's one place where problem can occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ipow` function will misbehave if the second argument is a negative number: it will run for a while and have implementation defined behavior when `e` reaches `INT_MIN`. You should modify the test `while (e--) r *= b;` as:

```
static long ipow(int b, int e) {
    long r = 1;
    while (e-- > 0)
        r *= b;
    return r;
}
```

Note however that `ipow` will cause arithmetic overflow for moderately large values of `e` and since you want a `double` result from `cfilefn`, you should use `double` arithmetics for the power function:

```
#include <math.h>

double cfilefn(int a, int b, int c) {
    return pow(a, b) / c; 
}
```